# Has Flutter v3.0.0 come with any performance gains?

Tags: flutter

I'm on the fence about upgrading to 3.0.0, mainly because not all my dependencies have moved there yet.

So I'm wondering, how critical it is to upgrade to it at this point in time.  If there are any appreciable performance gains in regards to iOS performance or jank I would do it in a heartbeat.

Is there any real world feedback yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research there were many new updates on ios, android, windows and even linux

According to the documentation it says that "Flutter 3.0 offers improved performance, better Material You support, and new Dart language features."

some of the other updates:

MacOS and Linux support
Firebase support
Improved fundamentals
Casual Games Toolkit

My opinion is that is is really good to stay up to date and I updated mine too
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Flutter support backward compatibility and most of the packages will still be working fine for a while, i recently upgraded and i has some packages haven't updated for 9 months now.